# How does scoped_lock avoid emitting an "unused variable" warning?

Tags: c++, boost, g++, compiler-warnings

`boost::mutex::scoped_lock` is a handy RAII wrapper around locking a mutex. I use a similar technique for something else: a RAII wrapper around asking a data interface to detach from/re-attach to a serial device.

What I can't figure out, though, is why in the code below only my object `mst` — whose instantiation and destruction *do have side effects* — causes `g++` to emit an "unused variable" warning error whereas `l` manages to remain silent.

Do you know? Can you tell me?

```
[generic@sentinel ~]$ cat test.cpp
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct MyScopedThing;
struct MyWorkerObject {
    void a() { std::cout << "a"; }
    void b() { std::cout << "b"; }

    boost::shared_ptr<MyScopedThing> getScopedThing();
};

struct MyScopedThing {
    MyScopedThing(MyWorkerObject& w) : w(w) {
        w.a();
    }
    ~MyScopedThing() {
        w.b();
    }

    MyWorkerObject& w;
};

boost::shared_ptr<MyScopedThing> MyWorkerObject::getScopedThing() {
    return boost::shared_ptr<MyScopedThing>(new MyScopedThing(*this));
}

int main() {
    boost::mutex m;
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(m);

    MyWorkerObject w;
    const boost::shared_ptr<MyScopedThing>& mst = w.getScopedThing();
}


[generic@sentinel ~]$ g++ test.cpp -o test -lboost_thread -Wall
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:33: warning: unused variable ‘mst’

[generic@sentinel ~]$ ./test
ab[generic@sentinel ~]$ g++ -v 2>&1 | grep version
gcc version 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6) (GCC)
```

Comment: It's a little redundant to end a question with "Do you know? Can you tell me?". :p

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Only one of them is redundant; both are _stylish_ ;)

Comment: @Tomalak Just one unrelated thing: I'd hate to see variable named `l` in real code :)

Comment: @Alexander: I'd hate to see a program that does utterly nothing in real code. :)

Comment: @Alexander: I would not, I frequently name short lived variables with single letters (or just a few). Overly long names do not necessarily increase readability.

Comment: You updated the code but not the error, i can't find any variable named t. :(

Comment: @Matthieu: it's not about short names, it's about using literal 'l' (or 'o', or 'O' for the same reason)

Comment: @Alexander: Ah I see, well, I'd say that if it's clear from context, there's no reason not to use one, but I'd be wary of mixing them with numbers for sure :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the question has changed since the other answers were written.

Likely the reason g++ doesn't warn in the current form is because `mst` is a reference, and constructing and destructing a reference has no side effects. It's true that here the reference is extending the lifetime of a temporary, which has effects in its constructor and destructor, but apparently g++ doesn't realise that makes a difference.

Comment: Yea, seems so. :( It's a shame that there's nothing more concrete here (it's not as if I could expect this behaviour to be documented), but I agree with your answer.

Comment: +1, the most likely explanation. It's worth noting that static analysis is rather weak in compilers and this is why such warning arise.

Comment: +1: When the compiler processes the temporary binding to the const reference it injects an unnamed local variable and then binds that with the reference. By the time it gets to perform the static analysis it probably sees code similar to `type __internal; type const & r = __internal;` and finds the reference *unused*

Answer (score 1):

If my memory serves me right, g++ has the unfortunate habit of emitting `unused variable` errors differently depending on the optimization settings because the detection works at the optimizer level.

That is, the code is optimized in SSA form, and if the optimizer detects that a variable, after optimization, is unused, then it may emit a warning (I much prefer Clang analysis for this...).

Therefore it is probably a matter of detecting what the destructor does. I wonder if it takes a conservative approach whenever the definition of the destructor is offline, I would surmise this equates a function call then and that the `this` qualify as a use of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is that your class has a trivial
destructor, and that g++ only warns about unused variables if
the destructor is trivial.  Invoking a non-trivial destructor is a
"use".

Comment: Sorry, question edited. I hate when people do that, but there was something I hadn't considered. As you can now see, this is not the only factor.

Comment: @Tomalak: So you edited the Q and downvoted an answer posted for answering original Q? Or is it some troll?

Comment: @Als: Do you now have a magic "see who casts which votes" ability? If so, it's lying to you... I didn't downvote, but whoever did probably did so because the answer does not answer the question. Yes, I know that that's only because I changed the question, but James is free to now delete his answer and then everything's equal. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: No, I don't have any magic ability and hence the Question mark at end of my comment & also the `Or is it some troll?` part. This query because it has been a recurring problem of trolls downvoting at random lately And also, I think it would be very unethical to downvote because an answer does not answer the question which was edited after it was posted.

Comment: Votes should reflect, at any given time, whether an answer answers the stated the question. If the question changed then that is indeed highly unfortunate, but it does not change the facts.